# Solidity code testing

Tags: solidity, testing

Is it common to test code only on the testnet/mainnet fork?

I am currently working on a dapp. The test code is almost complete and I was initially going to test the code on a mainnet fork using ganache, and deploy the code on the actual mainnet. After deploying on the actual mainnet, I was not planning to test the code further (it's expensive!).

Is this a common step? Or is it better to test the code on the actual mainnet as well?

Answer (score 0):

All the unit tests we perform on the local blockchain, like if you are using hardhat then on hardhat node (also Ganache is an option), and see the test coverage report (test 100%).

After that, we perform an integration test (some called it a staging test) on the Testnet network and see if all the things work as expected, if so then after that we push to mainnet.

You cannot test on mainnet, because once push to mainnet and if errors occur then you need to push a new copy.

Hope it clears your query!